# Writing a code to replace a character with another in VB in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VB. I need to write a VB script for my MS Word macro which would do the following:

1. Search the entire document for the characters '-->'
2. Replace this with a arrow symbol.

The following macro would simply add the arrow I want:

```
Sub Arrow()
'
' Arrow Macro
'
'
    Selection.InsertSymbol Font:="Times New Roman", CharacterNumber:=9658, _
        Unicode:=True
End Sub
```

The arrow symbol I want is like the following:
[image: Arrow]

Can any one help me??

Comment: You haven't heard of Find and Replace?

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I replace this: --> with the symbol I have mentioned above using Find & Replace?? If I want to replace with some text then Find & Replace would work just fine

Comment: You also have the macro recorder.... use it and look at the generated code. For symbols use an ascii table to find the code you need and put it in with Alt+numeric code ( hit numbers on numeric keys)

Comment: He knows the code.

Comment: I don't think you need to use code to do this - this is a standard function of Word - **Find/Replace**. On top of that, you can use AutoCorrect's *Replace text as you type* facility which will do the change for you. In fact, I think, as default, --> is defined as the Wingdings version of →.

Comment: I think AutoCorrect will work when you type a text in word. But here I am copy pasting a text containing '-->' to word. So AutoCorrect is not working. I have to correct the --> manually then. Not sure how Find/Replace will work as I want to replace with a special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can get from Macro Recorder:

```
Sub Arrow()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "-->"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(9658)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Or you can use an old `WordBasic` command:

```
Sub Arrow()
    WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="-->", Replace:=ChrW(9658), Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will give it a try & reply back

Comment: Thanks. Its working :). I was writing  `.Replacement.Text = CharacterNumber:=9658` . I don't have knowledge of VBA.

Comment: @SumitPal That's why I said you to use "macro recorder". It is an easy way out to get a hint on how to write a macro. ;)